# font size incorrect on using em unit

Tags: css, font-size

Default `font-size` for my code is equivalent to `10px` or `0.625em`. So as per this rule, to set the font size of `<p>` as `7px` I can use `0.7em`. But in my case browser is taking the fixed font size of `9px` (checked in "computed" section of browser) even if I decrease the font size of `<p>` as `0.5em` or less.

[image]

```css
body {
  font-size: 0.625em;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em; 
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.875em; 
}

p {
  font-size: 0.7em; 
}
```

```html
<h1>This is heading 1</h1>
<h2>This is heading 2</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>Specifying the font-size in em allows all major browsers to resize the text.
Unfortunately, there is still a problem with older versions of IE. When resizing the text, it becomes larger/smaller than it should.</p>
```

Comment: It's really strange - in your snippet result computed styles tell that <p> font-size is 7px

Comment: Works fine for me in chrome - shows as 7px - are you sure your browser isn't set up to use user settings rather than the style sheet

Comment: Maybe it is worth to set font size on `html` in px to make it same size on all browsers. Also, I'd recommended to use Chrome or Mozilla for debugging instead of Safari due to quality and representability of tools.

Comment: I can set the font size in px or may be change the default font size to 6px and use the equivalent em values, but still wants to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want font sizes in strict relation to the root font size (which is set in a a rule for `html` , not for `body`, and should be in `px`), you have to use the `rem` unit or percent, but not `em` (which will be in relation for the default browser size of a particular element or its parent)

Aditionally, most browsers have a "minimum font display" setting that prevents small sizes to become unreadable. Most likely this is set to 9px in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can not set

```
body {
  font-size: 0.625em;
}
```

You need to set `10px` to the body font-size. **Then the calculations will work as you expected with using `em`. Else it will take the default `font-size` set by the browser.**

```css
body {
  font-size: 10px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em; 
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.875em; 
}

p {
  font-size: 0.7em; 
}
```

```html
<h1>This is heading 1</h1>
<h2>This is heading 2</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>Specifying the font-size in em allows all major browsers to resize the text.
Unfortunately, there is still a problem with older versions of IE. When resizing the text, it becomes larger/smaller than it should.</p>
```

Read more about how to set [em font-sizes here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size?#Ems)

Comment: Thanks! this solves my issue. But just curious about how the browser takes default value of 9px?

Comment: @AKNair honestly I can not really reproduce the problem you are facing. I just knew how to solve it. This makes it hard to answer why it is `9px`. I think that most probably you have set a min-font-size in your settings somewhere. (The other reason could be with some rounding issues (16*0.625=10 but 16*0.6=9.6) but I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Just got the answer from Johannes regarding the 9px.

Answer (score 0):

As you say ***font size of p as 7px I can use 0.7em***, which is not correct because here your default font size is 16px. if

```
10px == 0.625em then
7px = (0.625/10)*7em = 0.4375em
```

And if you are using **`10px`** as your default font, you have to set the **`body`** and **`html`** font size in **`px`** i.e. **`10px`**

```
html,
body {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Check below snippet

```css
html{
  font-size: 10px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.875em;
}

p {
  font-size: 0.7em;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is heading 1</h1>
<h2>This is heading 2</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>Specifying the font-size in em allows all major browsers to resize the text. Unfortunately, there is still a problem with older versions of IE. When resizing the text, it becomes larger/smaller than it should.</p>
```